# Regex help! Need to strip down a string to digits-only

Tags: regex

Let's say I've have the string ">=3.0.0". Regex: `[^\D](\S+\d+)` helps to strip it down to 3.0.0 (https://regex101.com/r/XUxyEM/1). But when I've the string ">=6" Regex `[^\D](\S+\d+)` will return an empty result (https://regex101.com/r/XUxyEM/2) whilst I want to have 6 as result. How to change my regex so that it works for both cases. Sorry, I'm kind of a regex-newbie.

Comment: Try `\D*(\d[\d.]*)`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/XUxyEM/3). Or just `\d[\d.]*$`, see [this one](https://regex101.com/r/XUxyEM/4).

Comment: Yes, thank you @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Or `\d\S*` as in https://regex101.com/r/BNQY80/1

Comment: is the word boundary important? you need to be carfull with regex that you dont get accidental matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture  digit followed with any amount of digit and dots after any amount of non-digits, use

```
\D*(\d[\d.]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XUxyEM/3)

The following regex

```
\d[\d.]*$
```

will match a digit followed with 0+ digits and/or dots at the end of the string. See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/XUxyEM/4).